# Logic Test isn't returning expected result

Tags: python, logic

I'm attempting to search in a list and print a tailored response if uname_input = Admin, otherwise, a generic response is printed. The code exits when uname_input = Harry, Julia, Bron, or Natalie when I would expect it to return the generic response. I've tested the code and it returns False when the logic test is run which is why the generic response isn't printed. I would expect any response that was in usernames e.g. Harry and not = Admin would execute the generic response. Why is that not the case?

```
usernames = ["Admin", "Harry", "Julia", "Bron", "Natalie"]
print("The current users are:\n",)
for a in usernames:
    print(a)
uname_input = input("Please enter your username: ")
uname_input = uname_input.title()
if uname_input in usernames and not "Admin":
    print("Hello " + uname_input + ", would you like to change your username?")
elif uname_input not in usernames:
    print("I'm sorry, that's not a valid username. Please try again.")
    while uname_input not in usernames:
        uname_input = input("Please enter a valid user: ")
elif uname_input == "Admin":
    print("Welcome back " + uname_input + ", would you like to amend a user?")
```

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line `if uname_input in usernames and not "Admin":`

you need to have

`if uname_input in usernames and uname_input !=  "Admin":`

`and` joins two separate filter conditions, what you're doing is something like

`if (uname_input in usernames) and (not "Admin"):`

Comment: Thanks for that, i'm slowly learning and I appreciate your help! Would it not still be True because both conditions were met? Both conditions being in the list and not "Admin"? Or is it a case of the "not "Admin" not having a logic test e.g. "not == "Admin""?

Comment: Try typing it in python console, you'll find out. `not` isn't a word, it's a python operator, so "not Admin" => False. Do accept my answer if it works out for you tho

Comment: Hey man do accept my answer if it helped! :D

Comment: Done. Thanks again for your help - one step closer to being a Python programmer!